# Doesn't the following limit violate the sum limit law: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, gamma-function

The sum limit law states that:

$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) + g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)+ \lim_{x \to a} g(x)
$$
where $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) $ exists. Now, using stiriling's approximation of the factorial, we can show that:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x} = \infty \quad (1)
$$

However,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x} =&  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x) + \log(x-1) + \dots + \log(1)}{x}
\\
 = &\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x} + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x-1)}{x} + \dots + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(1)}{x} \quad (2)
\end{align}

Now $x$ asymptotically dominates a logarithm of polynomials, hence any limit of the form:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x-i)}{x} = 0, \quad i \in N 
$$
Therefore, each limit in (2) computes to $0$. And as per sum law, $(2)$ is hence $0$. However this contradicts the actual result of $\infty$ in $(1)$

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** My question is different than the one mentioned in the close banner. That questions asks how to compute $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x}$, my question asks why applying the sum limit law gives an incorrect limit for $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x!)}{x}$.

Comment: The sum law works for a fixed number of terms. Although you can have an arbitrary number of them, the number can't change as your limit-controlling variable changes.

Comment: The "duplicate" is in fact not a duplicate.

Comment: I agree that this is not a duplicate and I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum limit law applies to a fixed, nonvarying, number of summands. For example, you cannot invoke the sum limit law to deduce
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac nn = \lim \frac{1+\cdots+1}n=\lim\frac 1n +\cdots+\lim\frac1n= 0.$$